# Aliased coefficients error using ranked anova art() in R

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run an aligned rank ANOVA in R on some data (fyi- my data is not normal) on fat to lean mass ratio (a continuous numerical dependent variable), and I keep running into an error when including all 4 factors (all are categorical) that I am interested in. The problem seems to be including both 'treatment' and 'timepoint' in the same model since I can successfully run each timepoint individually with the same script or I can remove treatment from the model and run all 3 timepoints simultaneously. However, if I try to run the ANOVA on a model with 4 factors, I get the error below:

Full error:

---

Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
there are aliased coefficients in the model
11.
stop("there are aliased coefficients in the model")
10.
Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)
9.
Anova.lm(m, type = "III", test = test, ...)
8.
Anova(m, type = "III", test = test, ...)
7.
flat.anova.default(m, type, test, ...)
6.
flat.anova.lm(m.l, type = type, test = test, ...)
5.
flat.anova(m.l, type = type, test = test, ...)
4.
anova.art(m, response = "aligned")
3.
anova(m, response = "aligned")
2.
summary.art(model)
1.
summary(model)

---

The script:

library(ARTool)

model <- art(fat_lean_ratio ~ genotype * sex * treatment * timepoint, data = df)

summary(model)

anova(model)

My data:

structure(list(sample_id = c("0003A", "0004A", "0004B", "0006A",
"0006B", "0006C", "0038A", "0038B", "0038C", "0042A", "0045A",
"0109A", "0119A", "0120A", "0120B", "0130A", "0130B", "0130C",
"0161A", "0179A", "0198A", "0002A", "0002B", "0018A", "0030A",
"0063A", "0074A", "0101A", "0080A", "0080B", "0081A", "0124A",
"0116A", "0125A", "0148A", "0168A", "0190A", "0166A", "0172A",
"0152A", "0170A", "0020A", "0031A", "0017A", "0047A", "0072A",
"0088A", "0040A", "0041A", "0049A", "0061A", "0228A", "0228B",
"0228C", "0226A", "0226B", "0221A", "0246A", "0270A", "0293A",
"0267A", "0114A", "0122A", "0143A", "0115A", "0131A", "0133A",
"0132A_0142A", "0162A", "0191A", "0191B", "0153A", "0214A", "0151A",
"0185A", "0193A", "0340A", "0340B", "0327A", "0333A", "0352A",
"0416A", "0416B", "0432A", "0432B", "0373A", "0252A", "0251A",
"0238A", "0247A", "0315A", "0315B", "0299A", "0318A", "0319A",
"0304A", "0219A", "0230A", "0301A", "0301B", "0260A", "0282A",
"0282B", "0290A", "0290B", "0313A", "0225A", "0239A", "0239B",
"XT09A", "0236A", "0236B", "0248A", "0250A", "0295A", "0322A",
"0322B", "0306A", "0255A", "0261A", "0255B_0261B", "0294A_0261C",
"0323A", "0324A", "0274A", "0317A"), genotype = structure(c(2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("301",
"304", "786", "852"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("f",
"m"), class = "factor"), timepoint = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("t1",
"t2", "t3"), class = "factor"), treatment = structure(c(3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("20d",
"5d", "control"), class = "factor"), fat_lean_ratio = c(0.025974025974026,
0.0263157894736842, 0.0493827160493827, 0.051948051948052, 0.025,
0.0394736842105263, 0.0121951219512195, 0.0675675675675676, 0.0632911392405063,
0.0892857142857143, 0.051948051948052, 0.051948051948052, 0.0555555555555556,
0.025974025974026, 0.027027027027027, 0, 0.012987012987013, 0,
0.051948051948052, 0.0579710144927536, 0.012987012987013, 0.0526315789473684,
0.0684931506849315, 0.0384615384615385, 0.0394736842105263, 0.0379746835443038,
0, 0.0253164556962025, 0.0277777777777778, 0.0579710144927536,
0.0363636363636364, 0.04, 0.0133333333333333, 0, 0.0144927536231884,
0, 0.0579710144927536, 0.0434782608695652, 0, 0, 0, 0.0481927710843373,
0.051948051948052, 0.0123456790123457, 0.0289855072463768, 0,
0.0416666666666667, 0.025974025974026, 0.0416666666666667, 0.0526315789473684,
0.0547945205479452, 0.0294117647058824, 0.0294117647058824, 0.0428571428571429,
0.0357142857142857, 0.0161290322580645, 0.0476190476190476, 0.0147058823529412,
0, 0.0327868852459016, 0.0151515151515152, 0, 0.025, 0.028169014084507,
0.0253164556962025, 0, 0.0121951219512195, 0.0263157894736842,
0.0641025641025641, 0.028169014084507, 0, 0.0597014925373134,
0, 0.0135135135135135, 0.0704225352112676, 0.0416666666666667,
0.0819672131147541, 0.0980392156862745, 0.0422535211267606, 0.0447761194029851,
0.028169014084507, 0.0819672131147541, 0.0307692307692308, 0.0727272727272727,
0.0634920634920635, 0.0533333333333333, 0, 0.0441176470588235,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0263157894736842, 0.0357142857142857, 0.0158730158730159,
0, 0, 0.0188679245283019, 0.0166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.0217391304347826,
0, 0, 0, 0.024390243902439, 0, 0.0185185185185185, 0, 0, 0.0317460317460318,
0.0136986301369863, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0151515151515152,
0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0.0289855072463768)), row.names = c(NA, -126L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))

I did some digging on this error, and it seems to imply that I have some perfect multicolinearity between timepoint and treatment. Some searches said that setting singular.ok = TRUE might allow for the multicolinearity but I still got the same error.